# package.json for different environments?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have a node.js app which I've just deployed to Heroku which depends upon the [canvas](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas) module. However, that module requires the cairo graphics library and long story short, I need to use a precomipiled version which is included with [this fork of canvas](https://github.com/elspoono/node-canvas-heroku).

Normally, my package.json dependencies look like:

```
  "dependencies" : {
    "canvas"   :  "0.10.0",
    "express" :  "2.5.6",
    "jade" : "0.20.1"
  }
```

But in order to get my app to work on Heroku, I must pull in the fork from github

```
  "dependencies" : {
    "canvas"   :  "git://github.com/elspoono/node-canvas-heroku.git#master",
    "express" :  "2.5.6",
    "jade" : "0.20.1"
  }
```

Is it possible to have a "Heroku-only" version of package.json? Or is there another section in package.json where I can "override" the canvas dependency in dev environments?

Comment: Are you deploying the same app to Heroku and somewhere else? If Heroku is your only target, why the need to maintain 2 package.json files?

Comment: local machine, heroku machine, but I may add other environments in the future. If somebody else checks out the project, npm install will fail unless their architecture matches heroku's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never used Heroku but package.json format defines the devDependencies field, see [Nodejitsu cheatsheet](http://package.json.nodejitsu.com/). Then install with `$ npm install -d`.

Comment: I didn't think devDependencies would override different versions of the same package, but it does seem like it's working. However it seems to be using devDependencies even without the --dev flag. Is there an env variable it's also looking for?

Comment: You can configure npm to run in production mode with `npm config set production true` or the env variable `export NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION="true"`

Comment: This link is broken for me

Answer (score 3):

There's a tool called [penv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/penv) that looks promising.  From their site:

> Sometimes we need a different package.json properties for our different environments like production, staging and development. (Ex: jitsu deploys)
>
> With penv you can customize your package.json file with properties defined inside an environments.json file.

Actually going to try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a Heroku specific branch in Git and merge into that prior to deploy (ensuring that you don't merge over your package.json).

Comment: Then you're not deploying to Heroku ;)

Comment: Hahah, touché. I suppose I could've come up with a better way of saying "I wish there were a way to do it without git" :)